# Limiting hosts in Bosun graph

Tags: graph, limit, opentsdb, bosun

I need to create a TOP10 table of memory usage on hosts including a graph. I can do that in expression, by using **limit($query, 10)**, so it's good for alerts and tables, but I've got a problem with limiting hosts on this graph. Limit returns a number and I need a series to be able to draw it. Is it possible in Bosun to limit number of hosts in graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [filter function](http://bosun.org/expressions#filterseriesset-numberset-seriesset) can do this:

```
$q = q("avg:rate:os.cpu{host=*}", "5m", "")
$f = limit(sort(avg($q), "desc"), 10)
filter($q, $f)
```

[image]

In this $q (SeriesSet) gets filtered to existing, and/or non-zero results of $f. $f is a NumberSet.